No Mapping Rule matched - 3Scale
I am receiving 'No Mapping Rule matched' in my 3scale configuration, and i have no idea why.
In 3scale I have added the matching method as this:
POST
/one-time-password-sms/v0/send-code
In my API application the endpoint is accesed as follows:
https://mysiteurl/one-time-password-sms/v0/send-code
Please help me sorting this issue, I have already tried everything.
